# Renderizar Imagem com Rotativa Pdf (Asp.net Mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

Tenho uma Action responsável por gerar o pdf usando Rotativa...
O código da action é o seguinte:

```
public ActionResult PDFPadrao()
    {
        string header = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Relatorio/Header.html");
        string customSwitches = string.Format("--header-html \"{0}\" " , header);

        var pdf = new ViewAsPdf()
        {
            ViewName = "Modelo",
            CustomSwitches = customSwitches

        };

        return pdf;
    }
```

O conteúdo do arquivo Header.html é o seguinte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div>
     <img src="@Server.MapPath('~/Images/337946.png')"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu quero renderizar essa imagem no pdf, porém ela não está sendo renderizada, aparece apenas isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver?

Comment: Se não me falha a memória esse `scr` precisa ser um path virtual. Ex.: `https://seudominio.com/Images/337946.png`

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado! Me ajudou mesmo!!!